# Error: Unknown function wrapperList.size. Check spelling

Tags: visualforce

I have a list of a wrapper class which i am using to display values in a pageblockTable.

I want to render this pageblock only when there are records.

I tried using the rendered tag on the pageblock

```
<apex:pageBlock id="pbmInput" rendered="{!if(wrapperList.size() > 0,true,false)}">
```

This doesnt allow me to save the VF page

i get the error

```
Error: Unknown function wrapperList.size. Check spelling
```

I could have in my controller check the size and accordingly store true or false on a boolean variable and use it.

none of the list function seem to work.. Empty() also doesnt work. Are functions not valid to be used in VF pages?

Comment: What is the body of the `wrapperList` class?

Comment: its a wrapper class holding task,contacts and leads.. The issue is not with the wrapper class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the () off the end of size so it reads

wrapperList.size not wrapperList.size()